# Include category name in page template

Tags: categories, themes, get-the-title

The theme I am using inserts and styles the page title using this code. I would like to display the category name depending on whatever it is for that category.

I have tried a number of methods but none of them work inside this code. I can make the static title 'Blog Category' appear for each category but not a dynamic category title.

Any suggestions would be most welcomed !!

```
  <!-- Page Heading -->
        <h1 class="fl">
        <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { 
            echo(__('Let\'s talk about respect and equity', 'layeru'));
        } else if ( is_category() ) {           
           echo(__('Blog Category', 'layeru'));         
        } else if ( is_404() ) {
            echo(__('Page Not Found', 'layeru'));
        } else if ( is_search() ) {
            echo(__('Search', 'layeru'));
        } else if ( function_exists('bp_is_active') && bp_is_group_single() ) {
            echo(__('Discussion Groups', 'layeru'));
        } else if ( function_exists('bp_is_active') && bp_is_member() ) {
            echo(__('My Activity', 'layeru'));
        } else {                
            global $wp_query;
            $page_title = $wp_query->post->post_title;
            echo $page_title;
        }
        ?>
        </h1>
```

Comment: I just worked it out myself using this statement:

else if ( is_category() ) {   
echo(__(single_cat_title(), 'layeru'));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_queried_object` to return the name of the current category page you are on

```
 $cc = get_queried_object();
  echo $cc->cat_name; //display the name of current category page
```

Comment: Many thanks Pieter